# Getting HashMap from ((HashLiteral.SequenceHash) (args.get(1))).keyMap

Tags: java, freemarker

In my template method (implemented with TemplateMethodModelEx), one of the arguments is of type HashLiteral.SequenceHash. However, this class is private and I am unable to obtain the map directly from it. Only methods accessible are those of TemplateHashModelEx - `keys()` and `values()`.

I can hardly believe that the only way to get the map is to iterate over result of `keys()` and `values()` to reconstruct it. Is there some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, you should just use the `TemplateHashMapEx` interface, because FTL hashes don't always have `Map`-s behind, and they aren't even `Map`-s in their interface (like they can only have `String` keys). So even if you could get the `Map` out of  `HashLiteral.SequenceHash`, what if you get some other kind of hash as parameter?

If you really need `java.util.Map` interface to that hash, you better ask the `ObjectWraper` (`Environment.getCurrentEvironment().getObjectWrapper()`) to provide one for you. If your `ObjectWrapper` extends `BeansWrapper` (and in the 99.9% of applications it does), you can call `BeansWrapper.unwrap(theHashParam, Map.class)` on it.

As a side note, poor `BeansWrapper` will face the same situation as you did; it can't access the `Map` behind. It will not build a new `Map` however, just wrap the hash into `Map` interface. Would it be still inefficient, that's the problem of the maintainers of FreeMarker, and should be fixed there.